How to extract time from a dataset
I am working on a dataset using SSMS. I am still totally new to SQL—less than a month. But i am grinding hard to make the best out of it.
I am trying to extract time from a dataset so i could determine the peak time of an event. I was able to get the peak time but no time to show the specific time of event from my result. i used
REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 108), 'AM', ' AM'), 'PM', ' PM') AS Time

and it returns my system time. How do i get extract the time from the dataset instead?
Here is my code
SELECT  
   REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 108), 'AM', ' AM'), 'PM', ' PM') AS Time,
   CASE 
   WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Created_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 24 THEN 'After Hour' 
   ELSE 'Work Hour' 
   END AS Standard_WH , 
   COUNT(DISTINCT Ticket_ID) AS Distribution
   --Note: Standard_WH is used for standard work hours
FROM [SLA DB].[dbo].[data_challenge]
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, Created_time)
ORDER BY Distribution DESC

and here is my result
Time      Standard_WH  Distribution
--------  -----------  ------------
20:55:40  After Hour   135
20:55:40  Work Hour    115
20:55:40  Work Hour    108
20:55:40  Work Hour    106
20:55:40  After Hour   104


I'm not completely clear on what it is you're trying to calculate.
But i've created sample CREATE TABLE and sample data:
CREATE TABLE data_challenge (
    Ticket_ID INT,
    Created_time DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO data_challenge (Ticket_ID, Created_time)
VALUES 
(1, '2023-05-01 08:30:00'),
(2, '2023-05-01 09:45:00'),
(3, '2023-05-01 15:00:00'),
(4, '2023-05-01 17:20:00'),
(5, '2023-05-01 23:00:00'),
(6, '2023-05-02 07:10:00'),
(7, '2023-05-02 14:50:00'),
(8, '2023-05-02 22:30:00');

Here's a query that does something; but without an example of what it should return (or why) i can't really say if it's accurate:
SELECT  
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, MIN(Created_time), 108) AS Earliest_Time,  -- Extracts the time part from the earliest event in that hour
   CASE 
   WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Created_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 17 THEN 'Work Hour' 
   ELSE 'After Hour' 
   END AS Standard_WH, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT Ticket_ID) AS Distribution
FROM data_challenge
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, Created_time), 
         CASE 
         WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Created_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 17 THEN 'Work Hour' 
         ELSE 'After Hour' 
         END
ORDER BY Distribution DESC;

Giving results:
Earliest_Time  Standard_WH  Distribution
-------------  -----------  ------------
07:10:00       After Hour   1
08:30:00       After Hour   1
22:30:00       After Hour   1
23:00:00       After Hour   1
09:45:00       Work Hour    1
14:50:00       Work Hour    1
15:00:00       Work Hour    1
17:20:00       Work Hour    1

8 row(s) affected

dbFiddle

thanks. it worked fine and i got the answer i need  now

Don't forget to accept the answer if it was an answer.
